# Gradle: Copy application.properties file from sub project

Tags: java, gradle, build, task

TL;DR Create a FatJar, but copy the `application.properties`` file from a subproject into the build output folder (any of them).

Hello Everyone,

I've got a gradle project that doesn't contain source code in the parent project, but has subprojects which do. One of these subprojects has an `application.properties` file that I would like to have appear in my build folder.  The structure of the app looks like this.

```
ParentProject
|
|-datamodel(Sub Project)
|   |
|   |-build.gradle
|-datadb(Sub Project)
|   |
|   |-build.gradle
|-dataservices(Sub Project)
|   |
|   |-src
|   |   |
|   |   |-main
|   |       |
|   |       |-resources
|               |
|               |-application.properties(File I need)
|   |-build.gradle      
|
|-build.gradle
```

I would like to have it so that when I build the ParentProject, the build directory will look something like this.

```
build
  |
  |-libs
  |   |
  |   |-outputted.jar
  |
  |-resources
      |
      |-application.properties
```

As of now, I'm making my build script output what I believe is called a FatJar.  I'm not sure if this is creating issues.

```
jar {
   ...
   from {
       (configurations.runtime).collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

**What I've Tried:**

Everything.  I've tried the whole custom task route in the ParentProject build file

```
task copyStuff (dependsOn : 'subproject:build'){... 

task copyStuff and then copyStuff.dependsOn...

task copyStuff..{
   doLast {
```

No matter what, I've never gotten it to copy, and it's been a waterfall of failure the entire night.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Copy` task from `Gradle`, thats depends on `Jar` task

```
task customBuild(type: Copy, dependsOn: [jar]) {
    from "dataservices/src/main/resources/"
    into "build/resources"
    include "application.properties"
}
```